# Why did the close page flow include neither DS nor CV in the listed migration recommendation options?

Tags: feature-request

When I voted to close a purely data science question that appeared in the First Question queue and selected the option that it was more appropriate for another site, the AI meta was listed as the only option in the subsequent page.  Neither data science nor cross validated were listed.  Can configuration be updated to facilitate what it seems to be somewhat unanimously believed, that data science questions are better located in DS than AI?

REF: [Keras : get back labels from a model](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8298/keras-get-back-labels-from-a-model)